# define different positions in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

in the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula] at ($(1.85*\pos,0)+(0.4,0.4)$) {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

can different positions be assigned
for example for position 1 1.85, for position 2 2.85, for position 3 1.85

Comment: Can you provide the full code? I get an error about the `\pic` command. Also, do you want to alternate between positions 1.85 and 2.85?

Comment: You can replace `{0,...,5}` by `{1.85, 2.85, 1.85}` and replace `1.85*\pos` by `\pos`.

Answer (score 3):

You mean to shift the node position for 1cm? If this is case, than try:

1.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula, xshift=1cm] at ($(1.85*\pos,0)+(0.4,0.4)$) {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

2.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula] at ($({1+1.85*\pos},0)+(0.4,0.4)$) {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Addendum:**

3.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula] at ($(1.85*\pos,0)+(1.4,0.4)$) {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

4.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula] at ({1.4+1.85*\pos},0.4) {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

5.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} {
    \pic (cross\pos) at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross};
    \node[formula,above right=1cm and 0.4cm of cross\pos] {Na};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

6. etc

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answers, but your last example is not working.

\begin{tikzpicture} \foreach \pos in {0,...,5} { \pic (cross\i) at (1.85*\pos,0) {cross}; \node[formula,above right=1cm and 0.4cm of cross\i] {Na}; } \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Short inspection of example show, that in it was inconsistent use of variable `\pos` (in two places was by mistake replaced with not defined `\i`). It is corrected now.

Comment: The corrected code gave me an error message

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '1and 0.4 of cross0')

Comment: Do you load the TikZ library `positioning`? As you not provide complete MWE, I consider that you are interested only on picture code. Please, provide MWE (by editing your question) that I can see, how you test above solutions. All given code snippets I test in my "test-bed" which is rather overwhelming regarding to their necessities.